# Working with links in Word for Mac

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, microsoft-word-2016

I work with documents with a ton of links in Microsoft Word for Mac. Is there a setting so that the default is that when you click on the link, it edits the text instead of following it. When I was working on documents like these on PC you had to "control+click" to follow the link. Is that available on Mac?

Thanks!

Comment: Look in the various options available under Word > Preferences. And, it may call for Cmd+Click.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll take a look at that tomorrow and see!

Comment: I looked again and didn't see anything. Any other advice?

Comment: sorry, not having a mac, i do not. I suspect you should ask on the Microsoft community. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word

Comment: Okay, that's a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it is. Best alternatives I've found are:

1. Toggle field codes while editing with Option+F9. Once done editing, toggle back so links are clickable. The watch-out with this option is it may hide some text you want to edit. In which case:
2. Instead of clicking where you want to edit, hold down Command to change the mouse pointer from the clicking finger to an insert bracket, then click where you want to position the cursor. The watch-out with this option is you may end up selecting a section instead of inserting the cursor; just use the arrow keys to move the cursor around from there.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll give it a try. I've found too that if I edit on Word 365 in the browser, the command-click functionality is enabled, FWIW.